# How to tell users that you have changed the Android package?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have lost my android app keystore and I want to know:

Is there a way to redirect the users to the new application from the old app?

I do have access to the API but it's not a webview.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way to redirect to the new app. The only thing that you could try to do is to notify as much users as possible that they have to download new app.

- If your application supports push notification, send it.
- If your app handles errors from server responses by showing raw text in AlertDialog or Toast, you could notify user by throwing an error to each request with a custom message (but you need to make new routes to all the methods so that you will be able still use them in the new app).

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to show the notification in a way different from the usual mobile app notification?

Comment: If your app doesn't implement the features me and @TimCastelijns mentioned you will not able to show any message, alas.

Answer (score 2):

Normally there are many ways, but you are extremely limited because you cannot update the app anymore.

The only remaining option is to use some dynamic text from your API that is displayed somewhere in the app and hope your users will see it. If your app uses FCM, you can also send out a push notification for the users to read.